# Как создать navigation drawer, если для каждого его фрагмента должны использоваться разные toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть 5 фрагментов. У всех разные toolbar (где-то вкладки включены в toolbar, где-то он скролится, и так далее). Как создать Navigation Drawer для переключения между ними?
Во фрагменты я включаю toolbar таким образом

```
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```